# How do I do client side webp, webm fallback?

Tags: webm, webp

The best solution won't need to be recoded when Safari and IE finally support webp, webm.  Can javascript detect a failure to load a format and request the fallback image or media?

Comment: Can't you extrapolate this from the useragent? If not, I'm curious as to why that's not possible.

Comment: user-agent means the solution depends on the browser type instead of whether an actual image, media file failed to render. So it will have to be recoded when more browsers support those webm, webp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I found: 
https://modernizr.com/

It's tests for the presence of features without hardcoding specific browsers.  One of those features is webp.  Not sure if it supports test for webm though.